# how to prevent the possibility of running multiple instances of an application running on same port that started by linux script

Tags: java, linux, multiple-instances, kill-process

I have a script to start tomcat and java based application with runs on 8080 port. If I go to same directory and run that start server script this application try to start and throws exception as "Port is already in use". But when I look at `ps -ef` it shows as 2 instances running for that app. What is the best approach to make VM to terminate (force kill) that process when this exception occurs or kill this newly started process by adding some meaningful message into logs.

Comment: Have you consider to change start/stop script?

Comment: like what type of changes?

Comment: Check if port is in use and if yes stop the execution. But before this please check if this second process you see is really the seconds instance. `pstree` can help you

Comment: Added something like this( lsof -i tcp:8081 | awk 'NR!=1 {print $2}' | xargs kill ), But it is not killing the processes which are running on that port

Comment: You can use `kill -9` to "force" kill the process.